# Python Sqlalchemy: Efficient Query and For Loop

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a lot of data from SQL database using SQLalchemy.

```
some_data = db.session.query(some_info1, some_info2).all()

for key in some_data:
  # do something
```

This takes about 10 seconds for SQL query and about 0.2 seconds for for loop.

I tried the generator way as well.

```
some_data = db.session.query(some_info1, some_info2)

generator = (x for x in attendee_profile)

for key in generator:
  # do something
```

This takes about 0.04 seconds for SQL query and about 10 seconds for for loop.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? I am especially skeptical about the 10 seconds for for loop using generator, I mean, is using generator this slow?

Just to be clear, my goal is to reduce the total time taken (not the query time nor the for loop time).

Comment: I think you can use memcache.
Please see this link: http://bbit.co.nz/blog/2014/07/13/faster-sqlalchemy-memcached/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your SQL query is taking 10 seconds in both cases.  In the first example, `query(someinfo1, someinfo2).all()` is actually executing the query.  `.all()` forces the execution of the query.

In the second example, `query(someinfo1, someinfo2)` does not actually run the query.  It only constructs the query. When you start to iterate over it is when the query is actually run.

Long story short, focus on optimizing the actual SQL that is being run.  Use a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and look into adding indexes.  The problem isn't with the code here.  It's with the SQL.

Comment: Yeah, I did another day worth of research into this but did not find anything special. Thanks for the tip on improving SQL